# Use classes on io.js in a file not in REPL

Tags: node.js, io.js

io.js released 1.0.1 version yesterday and, as the developers say, it's now possible to use classes without a nightly build.

But I'm not able to use ES6 classes without being in the REPL, e.g.:

```
$ iojs --use_strict --harmony_classes
> class Person {}
> [Function: Person]
```

But it I write it in a file, it doesn't work:

```
$ iojs test.js --use_strict --harmony_classes
class Person {}
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:429:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:341:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:296:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:487:10)
    at startup (node.js:111:16)
    at node.js:809:3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command line arguments are not actually applied to iojs. Change the command to

```
iojs --use_strict --harmony_classes test.js
```

it will work fine now.

Comment: I cant't believe it was just where I put the "test.js". Thanks! :D